# click events executes without clicking in jquery drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.visit-website-link a').bind('click', function(e) {

    <?php 
    $visit_count = db_insert('visit_count') 
    ->fields(array(
    'nid' => $nid,
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    ))
    ->execute();
    ?>

    });
});
</script>
```

I have written this code in drupal tpl. but when i visit the page the query executes without clicking the link to visit.

Can anyone helps me? to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is your `php code` and `php script is a server side script` so it will not see that you wrote it in `javascript click event` so it will `executed automatically`

**For this** you can use `ajax` to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, because the PHP code gets run way before the JavaScript has even been looked at by the browser. What you need is a separate page with your PHP code in it and then to call it via AJAX like below. Notes: I removed a trailing comma from your PHP array. You can even return something from your PHP to be displayed in the success function.

PHP (query.php):

```
<?php 

$visit_count = db_insert('visit_count')
->fields(array(
    'nid' => $nid,
    'uid' => $user->uid
))
->execute();

?>
```

HTML/JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.visit-website-link a').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "query.php",
                type: "POST",
                success: function()
                {
                    console.log('Update complete');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```